# Mark all as read

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bit of a brain lock on this one.

**TLDR;**
How do I implement "mark as read" for million items efficiently?

I have a use case of marking all articles as read. Tens of thousands.
The solution I have now works fine for small number of articles, but it's very, very slow with big numbers.
It's essentially because for every read article I am populating one table with a new row.
It doesn't matter whether I do 100 thousands inserts in one transaction or I do insert into select ( bla bla bla ) it still takes ages.
I was wondering about switching to postgresql's arrays, but I'm not sure how this will work with hundreds of thousands items. 
Any suggestions what will be the best approach here?

I have 3 tables:

```
articles
- id
- title

users
- id
- name
```

and a table with mapping which article given user has read.

```
read_articles
- article_id - foreign key
- user_id - foreign key
```

Comment: postgresql arrays are actually linked lists, the n-squared complexity will hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you remove the foreign keys from the `read_article` table and create a unique index on both the columns. This should speed up the search and insert queries. To check if the article has been read you can use a subquery in the main query and when inserting the row in the table you could use an upsert statement.

I think it is a waste of time and cpu to link the articles and the user id with foreign keys as yes you do need consistency, but it is not that crucial.

Comment: I am not sure why you got -1 but that's actually most valid answer.
I have noticed that it's taking a long time to check fkey constraint
`Trigger for constraint reads_article_id_fkey: time=92356.367 calls=43629
     Trigger for constraint reads_user_id_fkey: time=717.707 calls=43629
     Total runtime: 93651.255 ms
    (16 rows)`
So I dropped it and now this insert instead of 93 seconds is taking 1,5-2 seconds.

If you have any idea how to optimise this further, please do not hesitate and let me know! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into read_articles (article_id, user_id)
select a.id, u.id
from articles a cross join users u
```

Comment: Unfortunately, like I said - It doesn't matter whether I do 100 thousands inserts in one transaction or I do insert into select ( bla bla bla ) it still takes ages.

Comment: @canto As in all performance questions lots of information is necessary. You provided none.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert  into read_articles
        (article_id, user_id)
select  id
,       42 -- User id here
from    article
```

Comment: Unfortunately, like I said - It doesn't matter whether I do 100 thousands inserts in one transaction or I do insert into select ( bla bla bla ) it still takes ages.

Comment: You could add a `read_until` column to the user, and treat all articles before that date as read. You could periodically clean `read_article` entries that are no longer needed because `read_until` has shifted. Or even more simply, assume that all articles older than 21 days are read, greatly reducing the number of articles you have to insert.

Comment: Hmm... That's an interesting approach. However, I'd like to maintain history, so user can see what he has read.
Thanks for the tip! :-)
Getting rid of fkeys greatly speed up the process.